# VBA code to change font color for 3 columns based on the value of 1 column (multiple tables)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

**The situation:**

I have about 2,600 tables in one .xlsx workbook, one table per tab. They're to be published online as PDFs but, first, I need to suppress frequencies and percentages in rows with frequencies smaller than 10. Mask formatting doesn't work with the crosslist option in SAS 9.3. So, I think the most efficient way is to change the font color in the appropriate cells to white. Unfortunately, conditional formatting doesn't work when you select multiple tabs. Using VBA seems like the best option, but I know very little about it.

Here's an example of the tables (I've hidden the rows for grades 4-7 for brevity):

[Example: Original Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzSMv.png)

**The Goal:**

Change the color of the font in cells with calculated values to white to mimic suppression. For example:

[Example: "Suppressed" Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvxTm.png)

Can anyone please point me in the right direction? I feel like this should be pretty straightforward but, every time I think that, it's the exact opposite. I saw a few similar questions, but none with answers that looked relevant to my issue.

Many thanks!!!!

Comment: If you're planning on publishing as PDF from Excel, you do know that the "supressed" values are still exported, and can easily be revealed?  Just checking.

Comment: @TimWilliams I feel like a total idiot, but I did _not_ realize that! It's been standard practice where I work for ages. Yikes! I'm going to have to find some other workaround. Hmmm... Thank you soooooo much!

Comment: You can make a temporary copy of the file and have your macro actually *clear* the values (or set to e.g. "redacted")  instead of setting the font color.

Comment: @TimWilliams - Yes! Thank you! That's what I would actually prefer to do! How do I go about doing that? Sorry. I'm a whiz at SAS and Stata, but a real idiot when it comes to VBA. I'm guessing it has something to do with ClearContents, but I'm not sure where to put that statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering side-question about creating a temporary copy for export:

```
Sub CreateExportCopy()

    Dim wb As Workbook, wbExport As Workbook, newPath As String

    Set wb = Workbooks("DataTables.xlsx") '<< your (open) data file

    newPath = wb.Path & "\ForPDF_" & wb.Name

    'this will create a copy of the workbook in the same location,
    '  with the name prepended by "ForPFDF_"
    wb.SaveCopyAs newPath

    'open the copy
    Set wbExport = Workbooks.Open(newPath)

    'follow one of the other answers here to process the
    '  tables in wbExport, but use (eg)
    '     c.ClearContents
    '  instead of
    '     c.Font.Color = vbWhite

End Sub
```

Comment: Oh! Thank you soooo much! I found `clearcontents`, but just wasn't sure where to put it in my macro. I've been trying to teach myself by recording a macro and making sense of it, but I couldn't do that step manually. You (and the other responders) are pure gold! Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Are they always in Column "`C`"? If not, you have to check that kind of stuff as well.
Does it always start at row 10?
As far as just looping through the sheets and values, if you want simple, this is about as simple as it gets:

```
Sub whiteout()
Dim c As Range, ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each c In Range(ws.Range("C10"), ws.Range("C65000").End(xlUp))
        If c.Value < 10 Then c.Font.Color = vbWhite
    Next c
Next ws
End Sub
```

`For each` loops are pretty intuitive, but be aware that accessing and changing things like this in a loop can be pretty slow on a major scale.

Comment: Thank you so much! I''m familiar with `for each` loops in other software, so this make a lot of sense to me!

Answer (score 0):

doctorjay.

I worked on a dummy table of my own, based loosely on your dataset.

I would use a macro like this one:

```
Sub clean_lower_than_10()
Dim Sheet As Worksheet


For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    For Each Row In Sheet.UsedRange.Rows
            'Columns where the frequency and percentage are: C,D -> 3,4
            For Each Cell In Row.Cells
                'Inside this condition, you should change the numbers for the column number that corresponds to the ones on your tables.
                If Cell.Column = 3 Or Cell.Column = 4 Then
                    If Cell.Value < 10 Then
                        Cell.Font.ColorIndex = 2
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Next
Next


End Sub
```

The colorIndex = 2 means white color for the cell font.

This solution assumes that your percentage and frequency values are always on the same columns on every sheet.

If this is not the case, you'll have to work on the code to make it work, but it think this will be a good startpoint.

My table before executing macro:

[image: Before executing macro]

My table after executing macro:

[image: After executing macro]

Notice that the value remains intact, but the font color has changed to white.

Hope it helps

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much! This worked perfectly! If you have a moment, would you mind explaining the role of `Next`? If not, no worries. I can always Google it. Thanks again!

Comment: Sure ! `Next` is used to increment the counter that is carrying on the For Loop. If your counter was a variable named **i** you could write the For loop like this : `For i = 0 To 10     'Do stuff  Next i `. That would be the explicit way to tell Visual Basic to add 1 to the counter. In my code (__For Each__ loops), there are no explicit counters, but internally, VB understands that at the ocurrence of the **Next** word is where it should increment its internal counter for processing the next item on the list.

Comment: Oh! That totally makes sense! Thank you so much for your help and for the new knowledge!